# Which type of connector to use for asynchronous trigger inputs?

Tags: pcb, connector, gpio-external-interrupt

I'm creating a rugged onboard audio playback system PCB.

I'm using 16 individual triggers that are simple asynchronous input signals making a contact closure to ground in order to trigger a falling-edge interrupt (All 16 GPIO pins have their pull-up resistor enabled) inside of my microcontroller, which will then play the appropriate audio sequence.

**The thing is :** You could wire pretty much *anything* to each trigger : an infrared sensor, a simple switch, whatever as long as it can close the circuit between this pin and ground.

I therefore need a 32 pin connector (16 pins connected to GPIO pins of my MCU and 16 pins connected to ground), but I don't really know what kind of connector to use in order for my product to be useable with most industry-standard devices that could be plugged into my trigger inputs.

I've seen screw terminals being used for this kind of digital I/O purpose, but also horizontal classic 2.54mm pitch pin headers, DB37 connectors or even RJ45/8P8C connectors used as 8 I/O pins blocks each (!)

Comment: Screw terminals are good but the cheaper ones can chew up your wires unless you have ferrules.  0.1" headers sound good but most connectors require a crimp tool.  I'm personally a fan of wire-to-board terminal blocks that have either spring plungers or locking levers.  Relatively secure and you don't have to supply or expect the end user to obtain connectors or the tools to work with them.  However the "rugged" part might be an issue.  How rugged are we talking about here?

Comment: Also, it sounds like you're planning on having this off-board connection that the end user can plug anything into go directly into your micro.  You might want to consider isolation or protection of some kind in case e.g. someone applies +24V to it by accident.  More robust ESD protection would also be something to look into.

Comment: @vir This system is meant to be used in roller coasters, which means high G-Forces (spikes of up to around 5.5G max) and lots of vibrations. As for the ESD protection, it's a good point, I'll look into adding the necessary circuitry to the design.

Comment: Spring cage tool-less terminal blocks would be a good choice for that.  They have a constant holding tension on the wire so there's no issue with over/under torquing a screw terminal and are far more vibration resistant than a standard 0.1" header.

Comment: Wire fatigue under vibrations causes breakage as well as worn contacts. You need to define and verify the vibration spectrum.  5g's acceleration is nothing ,try 100 G.